# Excel Sum if not Null String

Tags: string, excel, null, is-empty, sumifs

I would like to sum all cells in column B that corresponds to cells in column A which are not empty. However, in Excel, the term "not empty" is a bit ambigious: if a cell contains a formula, but the result is a null string, i.e. =IF(1=0,1,"") , it is considered not empty, even though the result is essentially nothing.

However, I want to exclude such cells.

The obvious thing to try first is

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"<>",B:B)
```

But this does not work, because the operator <> only says a cell is empty if it is exactly that: empty. If there's a formula in it, such as =IF(1=0,1,""), it is considered "not empty", as explained above.

In my Google adventures I've also learned that "=" is the converse of "<>" in the formula above, but this does not help me, as far as I can tell.

What makes my problem even more challengeing is that I want to include cells in column B which correspond to both text and numeric entries in column A...

I can think of various ways to "work around", but I'm actually after a solution where I don't have to add another column to my data and where I can leave my data as is.

Thanks!

Comment: How about `=SUMIF(A:A,"<>",B:B)+SUMIF(A:A,"",B:B)`? Also, it may be wise to set row limits like $A$1:$A$500 or whatever your range may be, for performance reasons.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman Actually COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S) are pretty exceptional in that the use of entire column references has no detriment to calculation performance. So, with only A1:B2 containing data within those two columns, the difference in calculation time between the constructions =SUMIF(A1:A2,"",B1:B2) and =SUMIF(A:A,"",B:B) will be negligible.

Comment: good to know @XORLX - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of `COUNTIF(S)`/`SUMIF(S)` I agree is a touch frustrating with respect to null strings.

You can try:

`=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,{"?*",">=0"},B:B))`

if the numbers in column A are strictly non-negative, or, if not:

`=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,{"?*",">=0","<0"},B:B))`

Alternatively you can switch to `SUMPRODUCT`, which does not suffer from such ambiguous handling of null strings:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(A1:A15<>""),B1:B15)`

though which has the drawback that, unlike with `COUNTIF(S)`/`SUMIF(S)`, you cannot arbitrarily reference as many cells as you wish without detriment to performance (hence my choice of an upper row reference of 15): in fact, the use of entire column references within `SUMPRODUCT` is a disastrous idea.

Regards

Comment: Thanks! That's quite thorough.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar with a `CUBEVALUE` formula which can return "" instead of 0.

To get `SUM` and addition (`+`) to work I used `=VALUE("0" & CUBEVALUE(uglyforumlahere))` rather than using `IF` statements to check if the `CUBEVALUE(uglyforumlahere))` evaluates to "" then having to repeat the `CUBEVALUE(uglyforumlahere))` if it doesn't.

I also threw an `IFNA()` in there as well, so the end result is `=VALUE("0" & IFNA(CUBEVALUE(uglyforumlahere),0))`