# How to use: Sum if is not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, sumifs, nonblank

I have an example with 2 columns in excel sheet:

X --- Y

1 --- A

2 --- A

3 ---

5 ---

1 --- A

Column Y was hidden by the formula: =IF(A2<=2,"A","")

I want to sum if column X if Y is not blank.
I use this formula: =SUMIF(B:B,"<>",A:A) but it not understand that "" is blank.

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Why not use a sumif on the x column: =SUMIF(A:A,"<3")

Comment: This is my example. I mean in cases Y column has blank value is not depend on X column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SUMPRODUCT:**

Use `SUMPRODUCT`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A6,--(B2:B6<>""))
```

---

**SUMIF array:**

Or enter the following as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B6<>"",A2:A6))
```

---

**SUMIF with wildcards:**

Using a formula by [XOR LX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35085827/6241235)

```
=SUM(SUMIF(B2:B6,{"?*",">=0","<0"},A2:A6))
```

---

Data:

[image: data]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @ QHarr Did your the second (sumif) formula run?

Comment: I used your formula  `=SUMIF(B2:B6,"<>"&TEXT(,),A2:A6)` but the result is 12. I mean it was not excepted the blank value

Comment: My Y column was hidden only the formula `=IF(A2<=2,"A","")`

Comment: You are so kind. Thank for your support. Please give me the answer if you found it

Comment: No way to use sumif(s) formula? :((. Use an array formula will make excel file run very slowly with a large of data and multiple conditions

Comment: Your answer is very good. But sorry I need the answer with sumif formula. If I select your answer, no one see my question and only see your answer. So my problem would not solved

Comment: No worries. I have added a SUMIF above.

Comment: Thank a  lot. It run :D

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, if you created the "Y" column just to help you solve this problem, then you can delete the column altogether, because what you desire is possible with the "X" column only:

```
= SUMIF(A2:A6,"<=2")
```

Comment: @ Downvoter, why the downvote? Seemed to me like a possible [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).